# How to resolve URL issues when deploying an Ingress Nginx microservices project with server-side rendering using Next.js on Google Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, google-cloud-platform

I’m running a microservices project with server side rendering using Next.js

I’m using an Ingress Service to redirect requests to the correct micro service and route.

When the app first loads up, the getInitialProps method of the App component makes a request to an auth microservice which basically is going to let the client know if there is a currently logged in user or not.

Now, to create the url to make the get request from the client to the auth microservice I am using the following url structure:

```
http://NAME_OF_SERVICE.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local
```

When I installed the [ingress nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) locally, it was installed under a namespace called `ingress-nginx`.

And if I take a look at the services under that namespace, I get that the name of the service is: `ingress-nginx-controller`

So the url to make the request from the client to the auth micro service would be:

```
http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local
```

This is all locally and it runs smoothly.

However, the problem comes when I try to deploy in the Google Cloud.

In the Google Cloud, using the Google Kubernetes Engine, I’m installing the [Ingress Nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) with Helm with the following command:

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm install my-release ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

This command installs ingress-nginx in the `default namespace`, and when I take a look at the services in the default namespace, I get that the name of the service is:

```
my-release-ingress-nginx-controller
```

So the base url to make a request from the client to the auth microservice would be:

```
http://my-release-ingress-nginx-controller.default.svc.cluster.local
```

However this doesn’t work and I get a `404 server error`.

I already tried removing the namespace and only referencing the service, like so:

```
http://my-release-ingress-nginx-controller.svc.cluster.local
```

But now getting:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND my-release-ingress-nginx-controller.svc.cluster.local
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of questions:

1. How did you install nginx ingress controller locally?
2. `http://NAME_OF_SERVICE.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local` scheme works only if your app is trying to send traffic to other pods/services within the cluster. **If your NextJS app is running in the browser (client side rendering I believe), then it needs a publicly accessible URL to the authentication service**.
3. It seems that you're consuming Nginx ingress controller's own service created by its helm chart instead of `Ingress` resource which points to authentication app's `Service`. Where is the Ingress resource?

Comment: Thanks!

1. I installed with Helm using the following commands:
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm install my-release ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx

2. As I am implementing server side rendering, the first time that the app loads, the request is going to come from the server, thus the request is being made from inside the Kubernetes cluster.

3. I am not entirely sure what you mean by "consuming Nginx ingress controller's own service created by its helm chart instead of Ingress resource which points to authentication app's Service"

Comment: If you're doing SSR, then you can probably hit the authentication app's `Service` without going through Nginx. Nginx ingress controller basically acts as a reverse proxy and L7 load-balancer which allows the outside traffic to enter into k8s cluster. For client side rendering (which happens in browser), you will have to use [ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). The ingress controller will take your `Ingress` resource and start accepting the traffic according to the rules specified.